# Can a Lambda Authorizer function detect when an IAM user has been disabled?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

How does a Lambda Authorizer detect if an IAM user has been Disable?

We have a two client servers of  Iterable and Punchh. The first one  uses a payload of just the base64 token of the username : password while the other server uses the username and password (password is masked).
These 2 servers are pushing (POST method) events down to our API Gateway. To avoid any ,malicious packets being sent down to the gateway, we use an IAM test user (dd_transfer in the example figures below) that can be disbaled once malicious packets are discovered. Thus the IAM test user should now be denied access to the API Gateways where both Punchh and Iterable are pushing their payloads.

When I have an active test user, they are allowed access to the API gateway whenever Punchh or Iterable webhooks push(Post)  data. However when that same user is Disabled (password is null) in IAM, that user should not be allowed to access to the  gateway. Unfortunately, the 2 external servers are still allowed access once the IAM test user has been deactivated/disabled. I don't want to program and search through a credentials report csv file using boto3 that's encoded to base64. This would expose too much account user info - very risky. Is there another way for the Lambda Authorizer function to determine when an IAM user has been deactivated?

Here are the screen shots below for code, gateway , and servers.

> Note that the payloads for the two servers are represented differently. Punchh webhook admin page  uses password and username while Iterable webhook admin page uses only the base64 encoded token.
> Thanks

> Lambda Authorizer Code

[image: 1]

> API Gateway Method (Note: Post and Get Method Requests are identical)

[image]

> Lambda Authorizer configuration

[image]

> Punchh Webhook page

[image]

> Iterable Webhook Page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I found a safe way to determine whether the dd_transfer user is enabled or not and that is with using the GetLoginProfile API. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_login_profile

If there is a valid password for dd_transfer, then a LoginProfile object will be displayed in the response message, a 200 response code is returned, and the access to the API Gateway will be given when the policy is generated (‘Allow’).

However if the password is null because the dd_transfer has been disabled, a *NoSuchEntity* exception will be returned indicating that the Login Profile for User dd_transfer cannot be found.  It’s blunt but at least I don’t have to worry about access being given to allow malicious events to bypass our API Gateway and into S3 buckets.

I have added a try/catch block to gracefully handle the error by calling the generate Policy function passing  the ‘Deny’ parameter in order to generate the Deny Access policy.

It’s a lot less work than using the Credential Report API and then BASE 64  decoding each record in the text/csv file to look for dd_transfer’s entry. The csv file doesn’t expose actual raw data  like passwords etc  but GetLoginProfile takes less to write up.  Then in the exception handler, I would make a call to the generate the Deny Policy.